# Why no match for my XPath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath

I used http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html to get `UserId` value on

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                    xmlns:paf="http://paf.mycompany.com/">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <paf:requestpafBean>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <arg0>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <UserId>?</UserId>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <DateNow>?</DateNow>
           </arg0>
        </paf:requestpafBean>
     </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

to test this XPath expression :

```
//paf:UserId[1]/@text
```

Why do I get no match ?

Comment: @kjhughes thanks I updated. I also tried to change my xpath expression with no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following XPath expression,

```
//UserId/text()
```

will select `?` as requested.

**Notes:**

- `UserId` is in no namespace, so you don't want `paf:UserId`.
- If there are multiple `UserId`, you can add `UserId[1]` to your
  expression.
- There is no `text` attribute on `UserId`, so you don't want `UserId/@text`, but there is a `text()` node beneath `UserId`, so you do want `UserId/text()`.
- If there could be further markup beneath `UserId`, you might want its string
  value, `string(//UserId)`, instead of selecting its child text node.

Comment: @kjhugues works perfect for soapui mocking. Thanks a lot you saved my day of work